# English equivalent for French "les attendus d'un procès"?

Tags: legalese, translation, french

In French the yet archaic term *les attendus* remains the traditional way to designate the part of text, in the report of a trial, which explains the motivations that led the court to its final decision.

This comes from the fact that this text is <strike>generally</strike> always made of a series of paragraphs, each one beginning with "*Attendu que*" (standing for "due to", "because", and so on), followed by the detailed description of a unitary motivation.

I even don't know if English trial reports are built in the same way. Anyway I can't reasonably infer to use something like "the expected": it sounds too strange!

So is there a real English equivalent for *les attendus*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such constraint on the form in which judges in the English common-law tradition couch their decisions. Judges are very jealous of their literary freedom. I don't *think* you could be held in contempt of court for suggesting that there should be a standard form, but I wouldn't risk it.

Solemn (albeit usually inconsequential) legislative and executive proclamations, however, employ the stereotyped formula *Whereas [A] ... and Whereas [B] ... and Whereas [C] ... NOW THEREFORE [X]*, so you will occasionally run across *Whereases* for pompous legal prose.

ADDED:
And in fact, after a little Google-Booking, I find [this discussion](https://books.google.com/books?id=oEw4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA181&dq=Whereases+french+law&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAGoVChMIg8XlwP6NxgIVwjOMCh2m6QAk#v=onepage&q=Whereases%20french%20law&f=false) of 'The form of a French report' in which the author explicitly refers to *attendus* as 'whereases':

> The grammar of a French judgment will cause only momentary difficulty; but it is perhaps worth mentioning that the judgment is framed as a single sentence, of which the subject and the verb occur at the very beginning and the very end respectively, and are divided by a number of ‘whereases’ (*attendu*, or in the lower courts *considérant*); these ‘whereases’, of course, contain the *motifs*. The actual decision will be found at the very end in the *dispositif* which starts with the words: ‘Par ces motifs. . .’